# Pointer to Struct pointer member

Tags: c, struct

I have "hash" which is pointer to a struct.  I'm trying to get it's member stats which is also a pointer.  I thought I could just do: hash->stats but that appears to return the reference stats struct.  The "->" should just dereference the variable on the left?

```
struct statistics {
    unsigned long long count;   
   ...
};

struct hashtable {
    GHashTable * singleton; //Single Hash Table to Store Addresses
    struct statistics *stats;   //Statistics Table
};

    GHashTable *ghash = g_hash_table_new(NULL, NULL);
    struct hashtable *hash = (struct hashtable *) malloc(sizeof(struct hashtable));

//Works but why isn't hash->stats ok?
    memset(&hash->stats, 0, sizeof(struct statistics));
```

If I try this at this point:

```
struct statistics *st = hash->stats;
```

I get:

```
incompatible types when initializing type 'struct statistics *' using type 'struct 
     statistics'
```

Comment: What is `struct m61_statistics` ?

Comment: @Rohan, Sorry I just updated it, it should all be struct statistics

Comment: @user994165 What you're telling us should be ok. So there's something you're not telling us. Perhaps you've mixed up some types somewhere, included a wrong header file, etc. Create a small, but 100% complete example with every piece of code required so we can look at the whole picture.

Comment: Judging from the error messages, the compiler is trying to tell you that it thinks the `stats` member of `struct hashtable` is not a `struct statistics *` but a plain `struct statistics`.  So, you need to go back and look at where your `struct hashtable` really is defined.  If necessary, you may need to look at the preprocessor output (e.g. with `gcc -E`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line of code

```
 memset(&hash->stats, 0, sizeof(struct statistics));
```

is plain wrong. The `hash->stats` is a pointer. Its size is 32 or 64 bits. When you take its address, like `&hash->stats`, the results is an address that points into the stucture, very close to its end.

The call to `memset` clears the pointer field itself and the memory after it, that is right after the sturcture. You corrupt some memory in the heap. This will result either in undefined behavior or a crash. You should write something like:

```
   struct hashtable *hash = (struct hashtable*)malloc(sizeof(struct hashtable));
   struct statistics *stts = (struct statistics*)malloc(sizeof(struct statistics));

   hash->stats = stts;
   memset(hash->stats, 0, sizeof(struct statistics));
```

This will init your data. Plus you need to free your memory when you are done with your data structure.

Comment: Why are you casting malloc?